# How to use "laravelcollective/html" with blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

I'm trying to pull data from folder so that a user can download it I'm trying something like this

```
{!! Html::link('public/{{$file->name}}', '{{$file->name}}') !!}
```

but it throws out this

```
 <?php echo e($file->name); ?>
 <?php echo e($file->name); ?>
```

Is it possible to combine those two and how can it be done

Controller part

```
public function download($file_name){
    $file_path = public_path('/'.$file_name);
    return response()->download($file_path);
}
```

It calls this error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
```

User will need to be able download different kind of files img/pdf/doc/xls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't nest blade within blade. You just do it once.

```
{!! Html::link('public/'.$file->name, $file->name) !!}
```

Blade will handle the parsing from there.

Comment: now i get the names but it still gives error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: